# Integrating the LAN9514 USB hub/Ethernet chip with Linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, usb, linux-device-driver, buildroot

I have a single boad arm32 computer running a buildroot image I made, and I wanted to add the LAN9514 USB 2.0 and ethernet controller chip. I believe the Pi and the Beaglebone-XM incorporate the same hardware.

I've connected everything (leaving off the optional eeprom) and I included the SMSC95XX as a module in buildroot for the driver. However, when booting with the new hardware connected, I see these errors:

```
[   10.300000] usb 3-1: device descriptor read/64, error -62
[   10.590000] usb 3-1: device descriptor read/64, error -62
[   11.300000] usb 3-1: device not accepting address 4, error -62
[   11.900000] usb 3-1: device not accepting address 5, error -62
[   11.900000] usb usb3-port1: unable to enumerate USB device
```

Like the Beaglebone-XM, I have the PRTCTL pins from the LAN9514 connected to the input enable signals on a mosfet in order to control the 5v power to the USB ports. However, the PRTCTL are never being driven high, so no connected USB device can get power.

I'm wondering if there's something I'm missing (a device tree entry, maybe?) in order to make this work. It seems to me like the driver should tell the chip to reset to its default eeprom values and drive the pins high, but I think I must have skipped a step in order to bind the device to the driver properly.

http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/net/usb/smsc95xx.c

If anyone has any ideas, let me know. Thanks in advance!

Comment: *"I've connected everything"* -- Have you checked voltages to the chip?  Looked at clock signals?  The one time I had a problem reading from a USB device, the board layout had swapped the USB D+ and D- lines.  *"a device tree entry, maybe?"* -- No, USB slave devices do not get DT entries.  FYI a USB hub does not require an additional driver.  The **smsc95xx** driver is for the USB Ethernet gadget.  Such a USB driver is installed only after the USB subsystem recognizes the device.

Comment: Thanks for following up. I have checked the voltages and clock signals. What I've determined is that it won't work if I power the SoC and the LAN9514 at the same time. If I allow Linux to boot and then power on the LAN9514, it works.

To get around this, I was trying to unbind all usb devices, load the module, then re-bind everything, but it still doesn't work. The only thing that does the job is powering the 9514 after the board has booted.

Comment: *"The only thing that does the job is powering the 9514 after the board has booted"* -- If toggling nRESET of the LAN9514   doesn't help, then IMO something is wonky.